# Docusign Embedded Signing with Composite Template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Given that I have multiple template, let's say:

Template 1: A and Manager need to sign
Template 2: Only A need to sign

Is it possible to combine this into 1 envelope and show it within the app?

The way I did it as of now in sequence:

```
* create an envelope for the template 2
* retrieve the uri
* call `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient‌` 
  with body specifying the return url (back to my site)
* get the embedded signing url
* create another envelope for template 1
* retrieve the uri
* call `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient‌` 
  with body specifying the return url 
  (embedded signing url for the above template)
* call `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient‌` 
  with body specifying the return url 
  (embedded signing url for the above because it needs different signer)
* retrieve the embedded signing url
* open the embedded signing url on the UI
```

The problem with this way is, if the user takes too long on the first document (more than 5 minutes), the url will expired, and they don't get to sign the rest of the documents.

So, after some googling, sounds like I'm supposed to use composite templates, but I can't find any example on how to retrieve the embedded signing url.

**NOTE: I'm using embedded signing, so I need to be able to retrieve the url that show the signing page, and also specified the return url once the signing is done.**

**UPDATE**
I use the API Explorer to produce the right JSON, and seems to work for 1 template, will try for multiple template and multiple user.

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=login&mode=basic

UPDATE:

I have created a JSON, and it run (both template are now in one envelope, and I can see it and sign it), but only with one user. How can I make it work, so the other person can also sign it?

i.e: template 1: 2 people need to sign on different place, template 2: only 1 people need to sign

Below is the JSON, with some random variable such as template id

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
{
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "customFields": {
            "listCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "2096"
              },
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "2"
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "email": "someone@email.com",
                "name": "Some One",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Occupant",
                "tabs": {
                  "dateTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "*ExpDate",
                      "value": "2/20/2018"
                    }
                  ],
                  "listTabs": [
                    {
                      "listItems": [
                        {
                          "selected": "False",
                          "text": "True",
                          "value": "True"
                        },
                        {
                          "selected": "True",
                          "text": "False",
                          "value": "False"
                        }
                      ],
                      "tabLabel": "ShowCOI"
                    },
                    {
                      "listItems": [
                        {
                          "selected": "False",
                          "text": "Y",
                          "value": "Y"
                        },
                        {
                          "selected": "True",
                          "text": "N",
                          "value": "N"
                        }
                      ],
                      "tabLabel": "BillingOption"
                    }
                  ],
                  "numberTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "*ValueOfGoods",
                      "value": "$5,000.00"
                    }
                  ],
                  "radioGroupTabs": [
                    {
                      "groupName": "Some Radio",
                      "radios": [
                        {
                          "selected": "false",
                          "value": "on property"
                        },
                        {
                          "selected": "true",
                          "value": "off property"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "groupName": "ServiceSchedule",
                      "radios": [
                        {
                          "selected": "false",
                          "value": "Yes"
                        },
                        {
                          "selected": "true",
                          "value": "No"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "*SomeLabel",
                      "value": "SomeValue"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "*SomeAddress",
                      "value": "SomeAddress "
                    },
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "clientUserId": "2",
                "email": "managerone@email.com",
                "name": "Manager One",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Owner"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "<templateId1>"
        }
      ]
    },  
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "customFields": {
            "listCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "2096"
              },
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "1"
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "email": "someone@email.com",
                "name": "Some One",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Occupant"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "<templateId2>"
        }
      ]
    }    
  ],
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
  "eventNotification": {
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ],
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "includeDocumentFields": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "loggingEnabled": "false",
    "recipientEvents": [
      {
        "includeDocuments": "true",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      }
    ],
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/documents/docusign/available",
    "useSoapInterface": "false"
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I'm using the function to retrieve the embedded signing url, with uri is from the envelope, clientUserId is the first person in this case 1 for someone@email.com. Am I supposed to call it twice or something for manageroneemail?

```
private string GetSignerUrl(string uri, string name, string email, string returnUrl, string clientUserId)
{
    string recipientUrl = _baseUrl + uri + "/views/recipient";

    RecipientViewRequestModel recipient1 = new RecipientViewRequestModel
    {
        clientUserId = clientUserId,
        authenticationMethod = "email",
        email = email,
        returnUrl = returnUrl,
        userName = name
    };

    // make call
    string recipient1JsonSerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipient1);
    HttpWebRequest request = InitializeRequest(recipientUrl, "POST", recipient1JsonSerialized);
    string response = GetResponseBody(request);
    string signerUrl = ParseDataFromResponse(response, "url"); // parse signing url
    return signerUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below JSON Request to add two templates using composite templates,

```
    {
   "compositeTemplates": [
      {
         "compositeTemplateId": 1,
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "email": "AEmail@gmail.com",
                        "name": "A Name",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "roleName": "A",
                        "routingOrder": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "AEmail"
                     },
                     {
                        "email": "ManagerEmail@gmail.com",
                        "name": "Manager Name",
                        "recipientId": "2",
                        "roleName": "Manager",
                        "routingOrder": "2",
                        "clientUserId": "ManagerEmail"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "sequence": "2"
            }
         ],
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "1",
               "templateId": "f9fd4d6f-834c-4632-a054-cedb3e79d123"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "compositeTemplateId": 2,
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "email": "AEmail@gmail.com",
                        "name": "A Name",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "roleName": "A",
                        "routingOrder": "1"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "sequence": "2"
            }
         ],
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "1",
               "templateId": "56645b6f-21d2-4838-b92c-4d44df591e41"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160114/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-k-bist-docusign-embedded-signing-with-composite-tem).